# 事前選択で選択フィルターを使用したい

Tags: c#, .net, ijcad

IJCAD2018でC#を使用して開発をしています。
事前選択で選択フィルターを適用した選択結果を取得したいのですが、用意されているCADの.Net APIに該当する機能が見つかりませんでした。
SelectImpliedに選択フィルターが設定できればよいのですが、オプションを指定することができませんでした。

該当等する機能か回避方法があればご教示をお願いいたします。

```
[CommandMethod("test", CommandFlags.Session | CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
public static void Test()
{
    SelectionSet ss;
    SelectPick(out ss);

}

// 事前選択の結果を取得
public static void SelectPick(out SelectionSet dst)
{
    dst = null;

    // 選択フィルタ作成
    var selFilter  = new SelectionFilter(new []
    {
        new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Operator, "<OR"), 
        new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT"), 
        new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "LINE"), 
        new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Operator, "OR>"), 
    });

    // 事前選択が設定されているか確認
    var pick = (short)Cad.SystemVariable["PICKFIRST"];
    if (pick == 1)
    {
        // 事前選択
        // ※↓の選択結果に作成した選択フィルタ(selFilter)を適用したい
        var retPick = Cad.Editor.SelectImplied();
        if (retPick.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
        dst = retPick.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editor.SelectImplied以外にも、Editor.GetSelectionメソッドでも事前選択セットから選択セットの作成が可能です。
Editor.GetSelectionメソッドでは選択フィルターが設定できるので、事前選択セットからフィルタリングされた結果の選択セットを取得することが可能です。